# How can I cd into a directory as root?

Tags: bash, sudo, cd-command

Let's say there's a directory that I don't have the privileges to access. Obviously `sudo cd foo` won't work, because `cd` is a shell builtin in every shell ever.

So far, I've just been using `sudo bash` (yes I know there are better ways) to get a root prompt. Then, I can `cd` into the directory to poke around.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to `cd` as root (unless you are in fact in a root shell)?

Comment: if a directory was owned by root and there was no global execute

Comment: That's not really a valid case. It may be useful to be able to read the directory, but that doesn't require the directory to be your working directory, i.e. you don't need `cd`.

Comment: yeah, i didn't realize that until the accepted answer pointed out that i could just `sudo ls`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nope, there isn't a way to `cd` to a directory that only allows root without being root. There really shouldn't be too many directories that have this limitation. Most of the time it's the access to a given file that's limited such as the `/etc/shadow` file or specific log files under `/var/log`.

You can use `sudo ls <dir>` to see them instead of `bash`. Also when using `sudo` to become root you typically want to set user (`su` command) instead of `bash`, so use this command instead:

```
$ sudo su -
```

You can also accomplish the same thing with a sudo's `-i` switch:

```
$ sudo -i
```

*excerpt from man page regarding `sudo -i`*

> The -i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified in the
>   passwd(5) entry of the target user as a login shell.  This means that
>   login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be read
>   by the shell.  If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell
>   for execution.  Otherwise, an interactive shell is executed.

For the files that you can't access you can use either of these `sudo` commands:

```
$ sudo tail /var/log/messages

$ sudo less /etc/shadow
```

Comment: Why would you use `sudo su -` instead of `sudo -i`? They both give you all superuser privileges though all you need is the CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH capability.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - I've never noticed that switch before. My original introduction to `sudo` was through Solaris environments and the version of `sudo` that was there did not include this switch. Looking through the [sudo changelog](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/changes.html) it looks like that option was added in 2004. Guess I'm dating myself with this but you asked 8-). I'll amend the answer to include both, thanks!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I agree. I prefer `sudo -Hi` because it sets the home directory too (it doesn't set home by default on my distro, the default can vary). If you don't, you may end up with root owned files in your home, if it creates new files there.

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't. You need a shell running as root.

Comment: And, as pointed out in comments, it's fairly pointless to `cd` unless you are running a shell or a comparable process.

Answer (score 2):

Right, you can't. Here's a workaround though:

```
sudo sh -c "cd restricted-dir; some_command"
```