# why cant I sudo cd into /root

Tags: shell, sudo, su, cd-command

when I run  `sudo cd /root` it says `sudo: cd: command not found` but it works perfectly fine if I first `sudo su` and then do `cd /root`.

Isn't sudo supposed to give me root privileges?

Comment: Related: [How can I cd into a directory as root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80346/how-can-i-cd-into-a-directory-as-root) and [Trouble with running cd with sudo as another user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92989/trouble-with-running-cd-with-sudo-as-another-user)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cd` is not a binary, it's a shell builtin so `sudo` is quite right to say it can't find it. Besides, even if you did have a binary which changed your working directory you would be right back where you started when it exited under `sudo`.

If you want to change directory to `/root` and stay there then you need a shell with the correct UID, hence your `sudo su` and `cd /root` (or, even, just `cd`) work as you expect.

Incidentally `sudo su` is redundant. `sudo` can already give you everything you need with the `-i` or `-s` options.